# HTML add path to sub pages

Tags: javascript, html

How do I add paths without .html on my webpages?

My main site: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

About Page: [www.example.com/about](http://www.example.com/about)

Another Page: [www.example.com/test/contact](http://www.example.com/test/contact)

Comment: Check about url rewrite

Comment: you can use extensions

Comment: @kokab the whole point is to avoid extensions and nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with the name .htaccess in your root directory
and add this code to it :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

but you need to use http server

Answer (score 0):

There can be two ways to go about this:

(a) **URL rewriting**: In the .htaccess file in your root folder (if there isn't one already existing, create it) make the following changes:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    # Check that the URL doesn't point to a directory

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f    # Check that the URL points to a file with the extension html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC, L]    # Finally, make the change with a regex and flags like NC which ensures that this rule should be case-insensitive, and 'L' stops processing any more rules if this one is used.
```

Here is a good resource for URL rewriting: https://aloneonahill.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

(b) **Create an index.html file in each of your folders**: This way the URL ends at the directory name and doesn't show the index.html leading to cleaner URLs (for e.g. example.com/about instead of example.com/index.html).

I am not sure about the issues with the second method. It does look clunky.